# has_and_belongs_to_many association in rails 4

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-4

I've done everything as in here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association, but it doesn't work. I found some answers in stackoverflow, but still it doesn't work. I've made association for posters and types. But when I specify the type of the poster nothing happens. There is no adding to DB, and no types in the  Poster's view. Here is my PostrsTypes creating table:

```
class PostersTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posters_types, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :poster_id
      t.integer :type_id
    end
    add_index :posters_types, [:poster_id, :type_id]
  end
end
```

Here is Poster model:

```
class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :types
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, :body, :publish_date, :user_id, :presence => true
end
```

And Type model:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posters

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Any ideas why nothing is writing in the DB?

EDIT. That's my posters_controller, if you need it:

```
class PostersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_poster, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :index
  # GET /posters
  # GET /posters.json
  def index
    @posters = Poster.all
  end

  # GET /posters/1
  # GET /posters/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posters/new
  def new
    @poster = Poster.new
  end

  # GET /posters/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posters
  # POST /posters.json
 def create
    @poster = Poster.new(poster_params)
    @poster.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @poster.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poster, notice: 'Poster was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @poster }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @poster.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posters/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posters/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
     if @poster.update(poster_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @poster, notice: 'Poster was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
     else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @poster.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posters/1
  # DELETE /posters/1.json
  def destroy
    @poster.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posters_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_poster
      @poster = Poster.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def poster_params
      params.require(:poster).permit(:title, :body, :publish_date, :type_ids)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, show how u specify the type of the poster.

Comment: Please tell us what "doesn't work" means. Are you getting errors? Is your computer spontaneously rebooting? Without symptoms, we can't help.

Comment: Yea, show the actual controller action please. Or might be better to gist the whole controller.

Comment: lol007, I specify it in app. While running localhost I have "<%= f.association :types, :as => :check_boxes %>" in my "posters/_form.html.erb". So when I'm creating a poster throw localhost or console, there is no writing in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got your `@poster` now. After you call `.save` on it, it either saves, or it puts some errors in your model. Check your validations, and output them e.g. with `@poster.errors` (in your `new`-action, since this one is rendered if the save fails) and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

try using    **:type_ids=>[]**

```
def poster_params    
  params.require(:poster).permit(:title, :body, :publish_date,:type_ids=>[])
end
```

This worked for me